# Execute files in windows with Python

Tags: python, subprocess, execute

I want to make my python program to execute a file in Windows. That means that if I try to execute a `.txt` file, it would open with the default `.txt` viewer. Is that possible?

I tried `subprocess.call`, but I get `WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`. The file I'm trying to run is a `.png` file.

Comment: Can you post more about what you passed to `subprocess.call`, and the full traceback? The answer is probably in there!

Comment: @mprat `subprocess.call(["C:\\Path\\To\\png_file.png"])` hoping that it would execute with the default png viewer

Comment: you need to use `subprocess.call("file.png", shell=True)` or `os.system("file.png")` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
os.startfile("myText.txt") #open text editor
os.startfile("myText.pdf") #open in pdf viewer
os.startfile("myText.html") #open in webbrowser
```

is how you should do this

however

```
os.startfile("my_prog.py")
```

is probably a bad idea because there is no way to know if python is set as the default to open *.py or if a texteditor or ide is set as the default to open *.py

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking for. No cmd window, just simply starting the file

Answer (score 2):

This will start the file with the registered application for `.txt` extensions:

```
import os
os.system("start myText.txt")
```

with subprocess you'll need

```
subprocess.call("start myText.txt", shell=True)
```

since `start` is part of the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a file `myText.txt`.
If you want to open that file through the command line, you would simple write `~$ myText.txt`.
So in Python, you can just run a cmd command that opens a file. Say:

```
import os
os.system("myText.txt") #Requires myText.txt and the python file to be in same folder. Otherwise full path is required.
```

This would open the file in the default editor, or if it's an exe file, just run it.

Comment: The cmd windows was open for quite some time (around 5 seconds), but it did the job. Thanks!

Comment: Even when you double click a file, it takes a few seconds to open the file (unless you have an amazing CPU or SSD)...